# How do I put an ion-content on top of an ion-navbar?

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I’m trying to implement a popup window in my app. Here is the basic structure of my html:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <...>
</ion-content>

<ion-content class = "popup" [hidden] = "isPopupHidden" >
    <...>
</ion-content>
```

So you see, I have a header with a navbar, an ion-content for the default page content, and the last ion-content is something I want to be on top of everything when isPopupHidden is false. The problem is that my popup section is always underneath the ion-navbar. (Note: testing shows that it displays above ion-header). So I need it to overlap everything, including ion-navbar. I’ve tried messing with z-indexes but that didn’t help. Any thoughts?

Edit: Here is an image of my problem. Notice how the navbar is on top of my popup:

[image: Page Screenshot]

Comment: Do you have an image? Or could you use stackblitz?

Comment: Why are you using an Ion-Content instead of a modal?

Comment: I'm not using a modal because that's not the look I'm going for. I want the popup to hover above the page with the page slightly darkened. Would this be possible with a modal?

Comment: That's exactly what modals are for. Having multiple ion-content on a page is not allowed in ionic and thus results in undefined behavior.

Comment: I want my popup to hover above the current page, with the current page still visible. It doesnt seem like the modal can achieve this